# Trigger with insert statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have employee table with columns (id, name, address, age). This trigger has another insert statement on same table.

```
create trigger emp_trigger 
on employee 
for insert 
as 
insert into employee (name, [address], age) 
values ('AutoCreated', 'inserted via trigger', 40)
```

Now when I insert something in employee table, trigger gets execute which inserts another entry in the table. However trigger does not gets execute further. I was expecting that it would create infinite loop, because the insert operation inside trigger would recursively call the trigger.

I want to know why insert inside trigger does execute the trigger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A trigger does not call itself recursively unless the `RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS` database option is set.

[This is done for obvious reasons!]

You can turn on/off at the database level with:

```
ALTER DATABASE databasename 
SET RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS ON | OFF
```

Ref: [CREATE TRIGGER](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx)